# Vlookup LEFT in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to understand what the below Excel function is doing. I have researched this but havent been able to find anything conclusive. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

```
(VLOOKUP(LEFT(E40,8),'this data'!$B$3:$H$360,7,FALSE)*F15),
```

Comment: Well, the documentation is pretty damn conclusive: [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-adceda66-30de-4f26-923b-7257939faa65?CorrelationId=b7567aae-2093-4126-8b1f-ed14e708b2e2&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB) [`LEFT`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-function-7f365ad7-0cd1-427b-9d86-f8625b5582b0?CorrelationId=376719c0-c01c-4b12-ab88-61a584af34f5&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). How exactly is it not clear?

Answer (score 1):

This function does the following:

1. Takes `8` characters from the start of string in cell `E40`.
2. Finds the value in range `B3:B360` of the sheet `this data` that is exactly equal to the result of **1**.
3. If found, then it takes value from the cell that is in the same row and column `H:H`.
4. And multiplies the result of **3** by the value from the cell `F15`.

Answer (score 0):

In this case LEFT is a separate function from the VLOOKUP.

LEFT is simply taking the leftmost 8 characters of the string in cell E40 and then passing this to the VLOOKUP function as the lookup value.

The VLOOKUP then looks for this lookup value in cells B3:H360 in the 'this data' sheet and returns the value in column 7 of that sheet for the matching row. Then it is multiplying the result of the VLOOKUP by the value from cell F15.